# Why my uitableview scroll range not correct after UIView animation to change frame?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewanimation, uicontainerview

I do a slide menu that slide down from top, but only the range of last item of table can make tableview scroll. 
If I show the menu directly without animation, it work fine like normal tableview.

Here is my code.

```
        maskView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
        maskView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.2)
        maskView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.view.addSubview(maskView!)

        menuVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuVC") as? MenuTableViewController
        addChildViewController(menuVC!)

        var frame = self.view.bounds
        frame.size.height = CGFloat(44 * menuVC!.menuItems.count) > CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.height - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.size.height - UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height) ? CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.height - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.size.height - UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height) : CGFloat(44 * menuVC!.menuItems.count)
        frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height + self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.size.height + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height

        menuVC?.view.frame = frame
        self.view.addSubview(menuVC!.view)
        menuVC?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {

            self.view.frame.origin.y = frame.size.height

        }, completion: { (isFinish) in

        })
```

Comment: what do you mean by `but the menu scroll range only at last item` ?

Comment: I mean only the range of last item of table can make tableview scroll.